# Using InStr() in VBA to flag emails

Tags: excel, vba, email-validation, case-insensitive, instr

I'm trying to make a macro that will go through a list of emails and flag potential problems by changing their color.

I was trying to do it by using the `Like` function, but I forgot that it's case sensitive and the resulting code looks kind of big and messy anyway. I know I could use `UPPER()` to solve it, but it's already a large messy looking code and I hoped to avoid that.

Is there a way I can use `InStr()` instead? I've seen people say it's a better option than `Like` and I've been trying to look up how this function works, but the explanations I've found online are difficult for me to follow.

To explain the code I have so far, it's designed to flag anything with multiple emails as Blue, anything that isn't an email as red, and anything within a list of popular public email domains (Gmail, yahoo, hotmail etc etc) as green. I've trimmed the list of domains down from several hundred to just three for simplification here.

```vb
Sub Email_Check()
    Do    
        If (ActiveCell Like "*@*@*") = True Then
            ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
        ElseIf (ActiveCell Like "*@*") = False Or (ActiveCell Like "*.*") = False = True _
        Then
            ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        ElseIf ActiveCell Like "*gmail.com" = True Or ActiveCell Like "*hotmail.com" = True Or ActiveCell Like "*yahoo.com" = True _
        Then
            ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
        
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Loop Until Application.CountA(ActiveCell.EntireRow) = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: `I forgot that it's case sensitive` - it's not. It [uses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator#remarks) the specified text comparison mode, which is `Option Compare Binary` by default. Nothing stops you from making it `Option Compare Text`. The entire thing is achievable via [conditional formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f).

Comment: I've never used option before. It does seem to work but it's strange that it sits outside the code. could it interfere with other macros attached to the File?

Comment: It affects all macros in the same module, like [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-compare-statement#remarks).

Comment: If you are concerned about its impact on other macros then place this macro in its own module by itself with the Option Compare Text

Comment: `Or (ActiveCell Like "*.*") = False = True` looks *very* strange to me.